# Cosmos Db DateTime query in nested collection

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to do some basic `DateTime` operations on a nested collection in Cosmos DB.

Here is an example of the document structure:

```
{
    "id": "9a8b63d1-0b35-477a-9eee-f44bd41cbbcc",
    "Name": "Some Name",
    "StoredReports": [
        {
            "Name": "Test 1234",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-24T07:26:51.2395361Z"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Test 1234",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-29T07:26:51.2395361Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am attempting to do is just do some basic operations on the `StoredReport.CreatedOn` field.

Here is an example:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.StoredReport.CreatedOn > '2019-07-25T07:26:51.2395361Z'`

But that is returning no records, and I would expect it to return the document but with only 1 `StoredReport`, I am assuming I am not querying this correctly due to it being a nested collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,your document contains `StoredReports` property and your sql querys `StoredReport` column.They are dismatch.

Then,`StoredReports` is an array, so you need to use `EXISTS` to query the nested document.

```
SELECT * 
FROM c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT VALUE s 
    FROM s IN c.StoredReports 
    WHERE s.CreatedOn > '2019-07-25T07:26:51.2395361Z'
 )
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery for more unwinding options.

Comment: Ah ok, that seems to be the bit of information I was missing. That returns a different data structure (as expected). But is it possible to get it to return the JSON like the original document (as if I was filtering the `StoredReport` array)? If you understand what I mean

Comment: @JamieRees Of course,please use:`SELECT c.id,c.Name,c.StoredReports FROM c 
join s in c.StoredReports
WHERE s.CreatedOn > '2019-07-25T07:26:51.2395361Z'`

Comment: @JamieRees Since you use JOIN, you can't use select * from c. However,you could define every column you want to filter,like: `select c.a1,c.a2,c.a3......from c ....`

Comment: @JamieRees Did i misunderstanding your requriements?

Comment: No i think that makes sense, let me give it a go!

Comment: @JamieRees Sure!

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, I'm pretty new to this concept but you have helped fill in some gaps. Much appreciated!

Comment: @JamieRees My pleasure.

Comment: It does seem to be duplicating the documents when running the query with `SELECT c.id,c.Name,c.StoredReports FROM c join s in c.StoredReports WHERE s.CreatedOn > '2019-07-25T07:26:51.2395361Z'` and I am not sure why

Comment: EXISTS is designed for this issue. @JayGong, I edited your answer to replace JOIN with EXISTS, please take a look

Comment: @AravindKrishnaR. Much appreciated for your edit,got it.